# R: calculation from a table with a loop

Tags: r

I have a data frame like this in R:

```
        start     end      gna
1     123492   134160       0
2     134160   135025       1
3     135025   145600       1
4     145600   316603       1
5     316603   520140       0
6     520140   667054       0
7     667054   668492       0
8     668492   682728       1
9     682728   786994       1
10    786994  1597518       0
11   1597518  1628584       0
12   1628584  1717391       0
13   1717391  1717835       0
14   1717835  1722949       0
```

"start" and "end" corresponds to positions.
I would like to calculate the length of each portion where I have "1" in the "gna" column, and have each of this length saved in a vector.

So basically, the first portion where I have "1" starts at 134160 and ends at 316603.
Its length is thus: 316603 - 134160 + 1

Then I have another portion starting at 668492 and finishing at 786994.
Its length is 786994 - 668492 + 1

I think the algorithm should be something where we explore the data frame line by line and:

```
if gna = 0, do nothing -> go to next line
if gna = 1, then start.tmp = start  -> go to next line
if gna = 1, do nothing  -> go to next line
if gna = 0, then end.tmp = end from the previous line  -> go to next line
then value = end.tmp - strat.tmp + 1, save it in a vector and  -> go to next line to continue
```

I would like the output vector called gna (because my data frame has also column gni, gno etc.) and I will do the same calculation on this one as well.

Please help, I have absolutely no clue on how to implement that in R!

Thanks!

Comment: You can compute the lengths as `(df[,2]-df[,1]+1)[df[,3]==1]`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is one possibility without loops using the `dplyr` package.

First, using `cumsum` we can identify the right portions.
Then we group by portions and compute the length of each row where `gna == 1`.
Finally, we look at the end of each portion.

```
library(dplyr)

df_new <- df %>%
  mutate(portion = cumsum(gna == 0)) %>%
  group_by(portion) %>%
  mutate(.length = cumsum(if_else(gna == 0, 0, end - start)) + 1) %>%
  ungroup

     start     end gna portion .length
1   123492  134160   0       1       0
2   134160  135025   1       1     865
3   135025  145600   1       1   11440
4   145600  316603   1       1  182443
5   316603  520140   0       2       0
6   520140  667054   0       3       0
7   667054  668492   0       4       0
8   668492  682728   1       4   14236
9   682728  786994   1       4  118502
10  786994 1597518   0       5       0
11 1597518 1628584   0       6       0
12 1628584 1717391   0       7       0
13 1717391 1717835   0       8       0
14 1717835 1722949   0       9       0
```

If you only want the total length of each portion, you can use the `slice` function:

```
df_new %>% filter(gna == 1) %>%
  group_by(portion) %>%
  slice(n())

   start    end gna portion .length
1 145600 316603   1       1  182444
2 682728 786994   1       4  118503
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply! The first mutate is working, it adds the portion, but the second mutate is not. Error: Error: Problem with `mutate()` input `.length`.
x `false` must be a double vector, not an integer vector.
ℹ Input `.length` is `cumsum(if_else(gna == 0, 0, end - start)) + 1`.
ℹ The error occured in group 1: portion = 1.

Comment: strange: just double checked and the code works for me.
Probably your start and end colums are integers: replace the `if_else` portion by this:
`mutate(.length = cumsum(if_else(gna == 0, 0L, end - start)) + 1) %>%`
I replaced `0` by `0L` converting it to integer

Comment: Awesome, now it is working, thanks so much!!
How would you proceed to have the calculation on plenty of columns?
Imagine, I have another column called "gni" that looks like "gna".
Could I make the first data frame with adding the two portion and length but called gna.portion, gna.length, and do the same for column gni. And then use slice for the computation where I would have another row with the name of the column (gna, gni...) and the start, end, portion, length? Not sure I am clear...

Answer (score 2):

Your dataframe is named df

```
tmp=rle(df$gna)$lengths
df$idx=rep(1:length(tmp),tmp)
```

df now looks like

```
     start     end gna idx
1   123492  134160   0   1
2   134160  135025   1   2
3   135025  145600   1   2
4   145600  316603   1   2
5   316603  520140   0   3
6   520140  667054   0   3
7   667054  668492   0   3
8   668492  682728   1   4
9   682728  786994   1   4
10  786994 1597518   0   5
11 1597518 1628584   0   5
12 1628584 1717391   0   5
13 1717391 1717835   0   5
14 1717835 1722949   0   5
```

and the juice

```
unlist(
  by(df[df$gna==1,],list(df$idx[df$gna==1]),function(x){
    tail(x["end"],1)-head(x["start"],1)+1
  })
)

 2      4 
182444 118503
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply, it is working! How could I do that for several columns? And obtain a vector name by the column? With a loop?

Answer (score 0):

Another method using `rle`:

```
a <- with(rle(df$gna), cbind(end<-cumsum(lengths), start = end - lengths + 1)[values==1,])
with(df,end[a[,1]] - start[a[,2]] + 1)
[1] 182444 118503
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply! It's working on the test df but not on the real one. I have this error: Error in end[a[, 1]] : object of type 'closure' is not subsettable. Do you understand it?

Answer (score 0):

Most succint method i found:
given `df` your dataframe:

```
sapply(split(df, ifelse(df$gna, cumsum(1-df$gna), NA)), function(i){
  tail(i$end, 1) - head(i$start, 1) + 1
})
```

returns your desire data as vector. Vector names are cumulative count of skipped zeroes before each group, but it's a side effect ;).

Comment: Thanks! It's working well with this df indeed, but not with my real df (which is longer, but is presumably the same so I don't get  it). It outputs something as well but not a vector, rather a list like this:$`145`
numeric(0)

$`211`
numeric(0)

$`248`
numeric(0)